# What happens when I create a reference to an object inside a thread?

Tags: java, memory-management

I recently started to learn Java programming and we just reach the Java Threads topic.
What I'm trying to understand is, lets say I have a `Thread` object which creates an instance of `Object cat` inside its `run()` method, as far as I learned (you are more than welcome to correct me if I'm wrong) the reference variable `cat` should be held in the heap (making it visible for all the "living" threads). However what I'm trying to understand is what kind of data is stored on the the thread's "private" stack w.r.t this `Object cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cat reference (pointer) will be in the thread stack, the cat object will be in the heap.

You can check this link if you want to learn more:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-06-2012/120618-jw-archive-under-the-hood-threads-and-shared-data.html

Comment: 10x it was very useful. "Inside the Java virtual machine, each thread is awarded a Java stack, which contains data no other thread can access, including the local variables, parameters, and return values of each method the thread has invoked. The data on the stack is limited to primitive types and object references. In the JVM, it is not possible to place the image of an actual object on the stack. All objects reside on the heap."

Answer (score 1):

No , reference variable will not be on the heap..It will be on the private stack of the thread...

when run method gets executed ..the object created will be reference-less, thus making itself eligible to GC..

Answer (score 0):

Your cat variable will be be on thread stack and its visibility will be run method. Main thread and all threads you spawn does not have any common variable except these you explicitly  share between threads and SO vars.

Answer (score 0):

When `run` is getting executed the object will be created in `heap` but reference variable will lie in private stack of `Thread` .